# What is the "correct" way to format json from SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, parsing

I have a stored proc that returns json. The proc works fine and when I call it in SSMS it returns a json object that I can click and see as valid json. When I call it through Visual Studio it does the same, and clicking into it and pressing return formats it nicely so it's readable (and not all on a single line). If I take the string and pass it back into the sql function IsJson, it also returns true, so I'm 100% confident that the json coming out of the proc is valid.

However, my frontend developer is unable to parse it, and it seems to boil down to something trying to convert it somewhere.

The json (as output from the proc) is:

{"APIResult":[{"ID":200,"Status_Message":"Success","Developer_Message":"Successful login for D56D10AC-3A74-42FC-8BB5-F783A6C0C556 33E4F907-F1E5-4F1B-8CA5-5521291E683A (AppID: (null)).","User_Message":"Successful login","User":[{"ID":"D56D10AC-3A74-42FC-8BB5-F783A6C0C556"}]}]}

Using Postman to hit the live API (or localhost) I get back the data I expect (as above) however, it wraps the entire thing in double quotes and escapes all the double quotes around each element, so I get:

"{\"APIResult\":[{\"ID\":200,\"Status_Message\":\"Success\",\"Developer_Message\":\"Successful login for D56D10AC-3A74-42FC-8BB5-F783A6C0C556 33E4F907-F1E5-4F1B-8CA5-5521291E683A (AppID: (null)).\",\"User_Message\":\"Successful login\",\"User\":[{\"ID\":\"D56D10AC-3A74-42FC-8BB5-F783A6C0C556\"}]}]}"

When I try to parse this in sql (using isjson) it returns false. However, parsing this same code though jsonlint.com interprets it as valid. Trying it through the parser my developer is using http://json.parser.online.fr throws it out as errors too.

At a push, I can tell my developer to strip the first and last characters and replace every \" with " but this seems a bit faffy.

Are there different interpretations of json? I've read that this is often caused by the calling app expecting a string that it needs to json-ify and because it's getting a json object it's json-ifying the json, but even if I force sql server to output the string as a string and not json, it still seems the same. SQL is definitely pushing it out correctly but whatever my developer is calling the api through returns the same format as postman, and doesn't like it. How can I ensure that what the calling code gets is what SQL is giving and not some weird interpretation?

Comment: SO you have a REST API returning the results?  The problem is probably there.  Also if you return the results FOR JSON directly, it may be broken over multiple rows in the resultset.

Comment: Yes, I didn't write the APIs, but yes. If I call the API directly in a browser, I get the un-edited format:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{"APIResult":[{"ID":200,"Status_Message":"Success","Developer_Message":"Successful login (ID: D56D10AC-3A74-42FC-8BB5-F783A6C0C556).","User_Message":"Successful login","User":[{"ID":"D56D10AC-3A74-42FC-8BB5-F783A6C0C556"}]}]}</string>

Comment: Sounds like the API is returning a string instead of the raw JSON.  That's the API's fault.  How to do that correctly depends on the framework the API is using.

Comment: Any idea where I should start to look if the error is in the api code? Doesn't the fact that it comes out as the raw format in a browser indicate that it's not there, or have I missed the point?

Comment: It shouldn't be wrapped in XML like that.  And also depends on what `accept` header the client sends.  But for a .NET API find the controller and ensure it's setting the content-type to `application/json` and either writing the json to the request body or using an appropriate response formatter.

Comment: The controller has:
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
da.Fill(ds);
message = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
return message;

Which kind of implies it is being converted to a string. How do a set the header on the output and make it return json?

Comment: That's really a new question with different tags, perhaps `asp.net`, and `asp.net-web-api`

Comment: David, I'm not sure it is a new question, but I posted it as one anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54680015/my-net-api-returns-json-as-a-string-how-do-i-make-it-return-json. Any help would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Try to deserialize the output of stored procedure. Use JSonConvert.Derialize in C#

Comment: can you give me a sample of how I do this please? I don't profess to be a C# developer. I can get by, but only just :)